# I tried to install tableau server on kubernetes but pods keeps on crashing with SIGTERM indicating exit request

Tags: kubernetes, server, tableau-api

we are trying to deploy tableau server on k8 but getting SIGTERM errors after multiple services get launched and then pod start crashing.
First by building image on Amazon linux AMI and then published it to AWS container registry. When we run the following command to build the image

```
./build-image --accepteula -i tableu-2021.4.rpm
```

Kubernetes manifest

```
# tableau-server-in-a-container-pod.yml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tableau-server-in-a-container-deployment
  namespace: biz-platform
  labels:
    app: tableau-sp-portal
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: tableau-sp-portal
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configfile
  namespace: biz-platform
data:
  config.json: |-
    {
      "configEntities": {
        "identityStore": {
          "_type": "identityStoreType",
          "type": "local"
        }
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: datadir
  namespace: biz-platform
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tableau-sp-portal
  namespace: biz-platform
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 1800
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tableau-sp-portal
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tableau-sp-portal
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 999
        fsGroup: 998
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
      nodeSelector:
        domain: biz-platform
      containers:
      - name: tableau-sp-portal
        image: <ECR_REPO>
        env:
        - name: LICENSE_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: tableau
              key: license_key
        - name: TABLEAU_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: tableau
              key: tableau_username
        - name: TABLEAU_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: tableau
              key: tableau_password
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 50Gi
          limits:
            memory: 50Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: configmount
          mountPath: /docker/config/config.json
          subPath: config.json
        - name: datamount
          mountPath: /var/opt/tableau
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /docker/server-ready-check
          initialDelaySeconds: 360
          periodSeconds: 30
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /docker/alive-check
          initialDelaySeconds: 600
          periodSeconds: 60
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      volumes:
      - name: configmount
        configMap:
          name: configfile
      - name: datamount
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: datadir
```

While I tried it with different configurations and good amount of memory, storage capacity (60 GB, 200GB).

Error logs

```
2022-03-18 09:18:41,040 INFO spawned: 'tdsservice_0' with pid 9228
2022-03-18 09:18:42,251 INFO success: tdsservice_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:18:45,980 INFO spawned: 'flowminerva_0' with pid 9324
2022-03-18 09:18:46,119 INFO spawned: 'webhooks_0' with pid 9325
2022-03-18 09:18:47,048 INFO success: flowminerva_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:18:47,131 INFO success: webhooks_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:18:49,255 INFO spawned: 'tdsnativeservice_0' with pid 9540
2022-03-18 09:18:50,592 INFO success: tdsnativeservice_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:19:00,456 INFO spawned: 'analyticsextensions_0' with pid 10012
2022-03-18 09:19:01,896 INFO success: analyticsextensions_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:19:06,769 INFO spawned: 'collections_0' with pid 10471
2022-03-18 09:19:08,196 INFO success: collections_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:19:26,454 INFO spawned: 'vizportal_0' with pid 11804
2022-03-18 09:19:27,174 INFO spawned: 'flowprocessor_0' with pid 11872
2022-03-18 09:19:27,820 INFO success: vizportal_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:19:28,896 INFO success: flowprocessor_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:19:36,965 INFO waiting for backuprestore_0 to stop
2022-03-18 09:19:37,901 INFO stopped: backuprestore_0 (exit status 143)
2022-03-18 09:19:41,972 INFO spawned: 'apigateway_0' with pid 12926
2022-03-18 09:19:43,384 INFO success: apigateway_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:19:51,567 INFO spawned: 'dataserver_0' with pid 13245
2022-03-18 09:19:53,309 INFO success: dataserver_0 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-03-18 09:20:12,535 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2022-03-18 09:20:12,536 INFO waiting for webhooks_0, tabadminagent_0, tdsservice_0, dataserver_0, backgrounder_0, licenseservice_0, clustercontroller_0, hyper_0, elasticserver_0, activationservice_0, contentexploration_0, clientfileservice_0, filestore_0, stack-traces-from-coredumps, flowminerva_0, cacheserver_0, tabadmincontroller_0, gateway_0, noninteractive_0, tdsnativeservice_0, flowprocessor_0, appzookeeper_0, collections_0, searchserver_0, apigateway_0, run-tableau-server, activemqserver_0, analyticsextensions_0, vizqlserver_0, vizportal_0, interactive_0, floweditor_0, metrics_0, nlp_0 to die
2022-03-18 09:20:12,610 INFO stopped: nlp_0 (terminated by SIGTERM)
2022-03-18 09:20:14,036 INFO stopped: metrics_0 (exit status 143)
2022-03-18 09:20:14,438 INFO stopped: floweditor_0 (exit status 143)
```

Comment: Could you add output for the error, logs? You mentioned "getting SIGTERM errors after multiple services get launched and then pod start crashing". So before that your pod worked without problems? What services caused pod crashing?

Comment: Yes sorry for missing that added the logs

Comment: The logs says that SIGTERM received after dataserver_0 entered Running state